# How to intercept calls to ICommand.Execute in PostSharp?

Tags: trace, postsharp

I'm new to PostSharp, and I want it to trace GUI interactions in my MVVM application. The idea was to use `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` to intercept calls to `ICommand`'s `Execute` method.

Interception works when applying my aspect to my RelayCommand implementation's `Execute` method, but I can't get any context out of it - I can only see `RelayCommand` and `Execute`, which isn't very helpful.

What I really want is the name of the `ICommand` property, and the containing class. I tried this:

```
[assembly: PerformanceLog(AttributeTargetTypes = "System.Windows.Input.ICommand",
    AttributeInheritance = MulticastInheritance.Multicast)]
```

But that doesn't work. I guess I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to intercept declarations from another assembly, as in case of `ICommand.Execute`, you need to specify the target assembly (IIRC WindowsBase in this case, i.e. `TargetAssembly="WindowsBase"`). However, this would get you into a even worse situation than you are when applying the aspect on `RelayCommand.Execute` method. Since PostSharp transforms only the current assembly, `ICommand.Execute` calls would get intercepted only in your assembly and for from PresentationFramework code that is likely calling the command.

Since you need to associate your `ICommand` properties with the caller, you would need to pass the context into a field/property after the RelayCommand is created.

If your code looks like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public RelayCommand _myCommand;
    public ICommand MyCommand => this._myCommand;

    public Test()
    {
        this._myCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.ExecuteMyCommand());
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

The simplest way seems to be to use `LocationInterceptionAspect` on `_myCommand` (and all other `RelayCommand`-typed fields) and when `_myCommand` is set you would push the information about the field (accesible through LocationInterceptionArgs) into the RelayCommand's instance (using an internal property, which you would be reading from your PerformanceLog aspect).

Similar way is to push the information in an interception of MyCommand's getter.

Probably the best way to apply such interception aspect is to multicast it everywhere and have a `CompileTimeValidate` method that identifies targets of type ICommand/RelayCommand and deny (returns false) all other declarations.